# How should TypeORM in a TypeScript project be configured so it works everywhere?

Tags: typeorm

I'm struggling to find a configuration that works for TypeORM in a TypeScript project in all environments.

For example, starting with this `ormconfig.js`:

```
var dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()

var connectionOptions = [
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "postgres",
    "url": process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  },
  {
    "name": "testing",
    "type": "postgres",
    "url": `${process.env.DATABASE_URL}_test`,
  }];

module.exports = connectionOptions
```

But then, when I try to start the application, I get this error:

```
No repository for "User" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
```

So, I add the entities to the config:

```
var dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()

var connectionOptions = [
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "postgres",
    "url": process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    "entities": ["src/entity/**/*"],
  },
  {
    "name": "testing",
    "type": "postgres",
    "url": `${process.env.DATABASE_URL}_test`, // TODO: fix
    "entities": ["src/entity/**/*"],
  }];

module.exports = connectionOptions
```

At this point, running the app in dev (`ts-node-dev src/main.ts`) works. But when I compile it and try to run the JavaScript, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\exp7\backend\src\entity\User.ts:1
import {BaseEntity, Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn} from "typeorm"
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

It's trying to load the `User.ts` source file instead of the compiled `User.js`.

The way I'm running my app in prod is by running `node build/src/main.js`, the problem is that `ormconfig.js` is still at the top level, printing `__dirname` and `__filename` shows:

```
C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\exp7\backend
C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\exp7\backend\ormconfig.js
```

How are you supposed to configure TypeORM to work in both development and production?

Renaming my entity to `User.entity.ts` and setting entities this way:

```
var dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()

var connectionOptions = [
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "postgres",
    "url": process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    "entities": [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  },
  {
    "name": "testing",
    "type": "postgres",
    "url": `${process.env.DATABASE_URL}_test`, // TODO: fix
    "entities": [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  }];

console.log(connectionOptions)

module.exports = connectionOptions
```

cause the same error, as Node tries to load a TypeScript file:

```
(node:19344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\exp7\backend\src\entity\User.entity.ts:1
import {BaseEntity, Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn} from "typeorm"
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: @Captain328: not sure if you want me to try the extensions or `entity` in the name. But how would this prevent TypeORM from trying to load `ts` files when in prod?

Comment: Have you tried `entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],`? And of course you should name the file with .entity.ts.

Comment: @Captain328: exactly the same issue. I updated the question with that experiment.

Comment: What is your working directory when running the `main.js` file? Have you tried running it inside the build directory? When you run `node build/src/main.js`, if refers all the .js, .ts files in the project directory. So the solution will be to run the command in side the `build` directory.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this problem is to import models as classes instead of trying to get the glob to work. I also don't use an ormconfig.js but keep everything in TypeScript with a connection manager class. So your example rewritten for me would look like this:

```
import {createConnection, Connection} from "typeorm";

import {User} from "./models";

export getConnection = async (): Promise<Connection> => {
  const connection = await createConnection({
    name: "testing",
    type: "postgres",
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    entities: [User]
  });

  return await connection.connect();
}
```

That can work nicely if you have a small number of models, but it doesn't scale real well. If you have many models, you can export them all from an index and then import them all from that index.

```
export * from "./User";
export * from "./Foo";
export * from "./Bar";
```

Now here's the import

```
import {createConnection, Connection} from "typeorm";

import * as models from "./models";

export getConnection = async (): Promise<Connection> => {
  const connection = await createConnection({
    name: "testing",
    type: "postgres",
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    entities: [...Object.values(models)]
  });

  return await connection.connect();
}
```

And finally dotenv is a little simplistic for doing this work for my tastes. I recommend you check out https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config and see how you can have base config, env-specific config and envvars all play together well.

Comment: This file you pasted, it's not ormconfig.js/ts, right? What's in your ormconfig.js/ts?

Comment: I don't have one, like I said. I don't use a file like that. I create a ConnectionManager.ts class or something similar.

Comment: I guess to explain a little more, in my apps I either call `await getConnection()` in some kind of bootstrap or make this a class and use the typedi framework to implement a singleton pattern. Now I can use `connection.getRepository(entity)`. The above isn't copy-pasted code, so I apologize for any typos.

Comment: I like this one, 

Did you get any circular dependency issues in the process?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue. The solution is to run the app from inside the build directory, not the project directory, i.e. do `cd dist` and then `node app.js` instead of `node dist/app.js`.

My project structure is:

```
my-app-name/
-- node_modules/
-- dist/  # there go compiled JS files
-- entity/  # entities in TS
-- migration/  # migrations in TS
-- app.ts
-- tsconfig.json
-- ormconfig.json
-- package.json

# ormconfig.json
{
  # database specific code is omitted
  "entities": [
    "./entity/*.js"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "./migration/*.js"
  ]
}

# tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [
    "app.ts",
    "entity/author.ts",
    "entity/photo.ts",
    "migration/1618859843962-AddAuthorToPhotos.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```