# Error when using TypeORM, and Typescript with folder path

Tags: typescript, typeorm

When using TypeScript with TypeORM and I set my entities to a file path for .js files, I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:...\Projects\orders-api\bin\models\entities\Address.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of ...\Projects\orders-api\bin\models\entities\Address.js from ...\Projects\orders-api\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename Address.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from c:\Users\mrivera\Projects\orders-api\package.json.
```

I am using Typescript - 4.2.3, TypeORM - 0.2.31

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module":"ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "bin",
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["tests", "node_modules", "lib", "bin", "dist"]
}
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-api",
  "version": "0.0.12",
  "description": "...",
  "license": "ISC",
  "author": "Me",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/server.js",
    "build": "npm i && tsc",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: currently no test specified\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mssql": "^6.3.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "syswide-cas": "^5.3.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.31",
    "uuid-mongodb": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.35"
  }
}
```

I do not use an ormconfig.json file since I have to set the configuration values during runtime of the application.
Here is an example of what my Connection Options are:

```
return createConnection({
    name: "default",
    type: "mssql",
    host: this._server,
    username: this._user_name,
    password: this._password,
    database: this._database,
    extra: true,
    options: {
        isolation: "READ_UNCOMMITTED",
    },
    entities: [
        `${this._entity_path}/entities/*.js`
    ],
})
```

I have verified during using the debugger that the entity path is correct.

To help, here is an example of one of my entities (Address.ts):

```
import { Column, Entity, Index, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

import { Patient } from './Patient.js';
import { PatientNextOfKin } from './PatientNextOfKin.js';

@Index("PK__Address__3213E83F7240D5FD", ["id"], { unique: true })
@Entity("Address", { schema: "Orders" })
export class Address {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int", name: "id" })
  id!: number;

  @Column("nvarchar", { name: "line", length: 500 })
  line!: string;

  @Column("nvarchar", { name: "line2", length: 100 })
  line2!: string;

  @Column("nvarchar", { name: "city", length: 100 })
  city!: string;

  @Column("nvarchar", { name: "state", length: 2 })
  state!: string;

  @Column("nvarchar", { name: "zip", length: 10 })
  zip!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Patient, (patient) => patient.address)
  patients!: Patient[];

  @OneToMany(
    () => PatientNextOfKin,
    (patientNextOfKin) => patientNextOfKin.address
  )
  patientNextOfKins!: PatientNextOfKin[];
  
}
```

Using the tsc command the code is transpiled to the bin folder to .js files

Comment: Could you rename `Address.js` to `Address.ts` since you're using Typescript?

Comment: The code is written in typescript. The code is transpiled to .js files, which are placed in the bin folder.

Comment: Did you get solution to this?

Comment: @PeterNgesh: I have tried a variety of different approaches such as using a barrel file. I could not get anything to work. I ended up using a different library since I could not find a solution tp this problem.

Comment: @thxmike Thank you. I was able to figure out  the problem on mine. I will post my solution here

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on my app, a possible workaround is something like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62450486/11096288):

In your `entities` folder, you can create an `index.ts`:

```
export * from './Patient.js';
export * from './PatientNextOfKin.js';
export * from './Address.js';
```

And your `createConnection` will become:

```
import * as entities from "./entities/index.js";

//...

return createConnection({
    // ...
    entities: [
        ...Object.values(entities)
    ],
})
```